# Laravel - Save Many to Many, how to combine two arrays in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a situation when it comes to iterating two arrangements to save the information of both in a table. The code below is incorrect, but it is the essence of what I want to do.

```
    $userid = request()->input('user_id');
    $scores = request()->input('score');
    $courses = new Course(request(['course_id']));

    foreach ($scores as $score AND $courses as $course){

        $courses->users()->attach($userid,['score'=>$score, 'course_id' =>$course]);

    }
```

I have been using the function of combining arrays but the only thing it does is to combine the keys of an array with the values of another one and it is not what I want.

```
    foreach (array_combine($scores, $courses)  as $score => $course){

        $courses->users()->attach($userid,['score'=>$score, 'course_id' =>$course]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```php
foreach($scores as $index => $score) {
  $courses->users()->attach($userid, ['score' => $score, 'course_id' => $courses[$index]]);
}
```

Pay attention that `$courses` and `$scores` both need to be arrays. Double check if this line `$courses = new Course(request(['course_id']));` actually creates `$courses` array.

Hope it helps.